# how to convert java array to DataInputStream or DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I need to convert an `array` to  `DataInputStream` or `DataOutputStream`. And then reconvert to that type of `array`

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. What is your question? What have you tried? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Are you wanting to send the array through the stream (consider using an `Object{Input|Output}Stream`, or by send the array length followed by the array elements one at a time), or capture the bytes of the stream in a `byte` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so we have two part here: 
1. Converting **byteArray** to **inputStream** :

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { 0xC, 0xA, 0xF, 0xE };
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
```

2. And this is how to convert an **inputStream** to a **byteArray** (you also have to import the IOUtils)

   InputStream in; 
   byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);

**Edit** : if you have an byteArray you need first to convert it to intArray like this

```
IntBuffer intBuf =
   ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
     .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
     .asIntBuffer();
 int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
 intBuf.get(array);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.how can I use this for a int array?

Comment: I updated the answer for you, I'm getting downvotes for having answered you, I probably should't, so please next time try something then ask the question and don't forget to accept my answer.